# Bug with check-sat when passed assumptions

Tags: z3, smt

We ran into this seemingly severe bug today.

Consider [this Z3 script](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/3DU). (Reproduced below for completeness.)

The formula is unsat. We first check the formula with an additional assumption, and get `unsat` as expected. However, when we check it a second time, without any assumption, Z3 now reports `sat`. When we ask for a model, we get an obviously wrong one (essentially contradicting `(distinct 1 1)`).

If we surround the first `(check-sat ...)` with `(push)` and `(pop)`, the result is as expected. This suggests that when `check-sat` is passed additional assumptions, it applies unsound simplifications to the context.

Are we perhaps using `check-sat` in an incorrect way?

```
(set-option :produce-unsat-cores true)
(set-option :produce-models true)

(declare-const start25 Bool)
(declare-const bf07 Bool)
(declare-const bf19 Bool)
(declare-const lt06 Int)
(declare-const ef08 Int)
(declare-const ef110 Int)

(declare-fun whileM4 (Int) Int)

(assert start25)
(assert (=> start25 (distinct lt06 1)))
(assert (=> start25 (= lt06 (whileM4 0))))
(assert (=> (not bf07) (= ef08 0)))
(assert (=> bf07 (= ef08 (whileM4 (+ 0 1)))))
(assert (=> start25 (not (< (whileM4 0) 1))))
(assert (=> start25 (= (whileM4 0) ef08)))
(assert (=> start25 (and (=> bf07 (< 0 1)) (=> (< 0 1) bf07))))
(assert (=> (not bf19) (= ef110 (+ 0 1))))
(assert (=> bf19 (= ef110 (whileM4 (+ (+ 0 1) 1)))))
(assert (=> bf07 (not (< (whileM4 (+ 0 1)) 1))))
(assert (=> bf07 (= (whileM4 (+ 0 1)) ef110)))
(assert (=> bf07 (and (=> bf19 (< (+ 0 1) 1)) (=> (< (+ 0 1) 1) bf19))))

(push) ; comment out to produce bug
(check-sat (not bf19))
(pop)  ; comment out to produce bug

(check-sat)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the bug. The bug affects all Z3 <= v4.3.1.
I fixed this bug, and the fix is already available at codeplex.

http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/8c211dd4fcd3

To get the work-in-progress branch, we use

```
git clone https://git01.codeplex.com/z3 -b unstable
```

Using the "work-in-progress" branch may be inconvenient since you also get other updates and modifications. So, another option is to manually apply the fix to the version you are using. 
Note that, the fix is a very [small modification](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/8c211dd4fcd3).

Comment: What do you know, 4.3.1 (and master on git) is the latest we tried :) Thanks!

Comment: I meant, I fixed the bug after you reported it :)

Comment: I see :) by the way, are we correct in observing that surrounding with push/pop prevents the bug, or is it a coincidence?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The push/pop will prevent the bug. In Z3, there are two kinds of `push`: internal and user/external. We can't perform an internal `push` in an inconsistent context because we will loose all the information describing the inconsistency when we execute an (internal) `pop`. For user/external pushes, Z3 will preserve all necessary information. By performing the user/external `push` before `check-sat` you prevent the scenario that triggers the bug. I described the scenario in the "release notes".

Comment: (...and as a good academic, I should point that [Etienne Kneuss](http://stackoverflow.com/users/849529/etienne-kneuss) was the one who first noticed the inconsistent results.)